# Execute "Load more products" after page current items have been parsed

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I want create a loop to execute "load more products..." so that all items can be displayed on one page. I'm not sure where to start with this and in which language (Javascript,php) it should be done in.

[Website I am referring to](http://m.countdown.co.nz/DepartmentItems/14?deals=False)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require a combination of a server-side and client-side script.
The server side would need to cut the products list into sections that are of the best size to load.
The client would need to implement an ajax script that loads each section once the previous one has finished loading.

If you are not experienced enough with javascript, you can easily use a library such as jQuery to do most of the technical client work for you.

Comment: Could you give me an idea where to start or a simple example that I could work with?

Comment: @DrDog unfortunately not, a script such as this has a few small but important unique things to it (such as exactly how the client interacts with the server script) that make it impossible to give you an actual base to work from.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the UX feature you are looking for is called a Lazy Load, there are javascript libs to handle that, check out jquery.